# Is there a way to draw lines (x,y)-(x2,y2) in ASP.NET pages?

Tags: asp.net, drawing, gantt-chart

Not animated of course, but good for displaying data visually such as Gantt chart etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use a javascript graphs library to draw your graphs and charts?

check out these [flot examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html) - maybe [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is what you need

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if i understand your question but if you want to draw images dynamically you can use GDI+ and the [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace. Look [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial123_Working-with-GDIplus-in-ASP.NET.html) for an example.

Edit: Sorry i did not see the gannt tag. Check out the following [control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/EventCalendarControl.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could create the image using the Graphics class, then output the file to the filesystem, and link an Image control of some sort to that image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Chart control in ASP.NET 3.5 with a bunch of features and options, maybe you'll like it.
You can read a quick review [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/11/25/getting-started-with-the-asp-net-3-5-chart-control.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The [Walter Zorn javascript library](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm) may be your answer.